# angular date display GMT time

Tags: angular, gmt, date-pipe

In my angular application I have a date string (2023-06-20T06:15:00) which I need to format and display as

06/20/2023 at 06:15PM (GMT-5)

1. I am using Angular Datepipe like below and it displays, Tue Jun 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

   new Date(
   this.datePipe.transform(
   new Date(2023-06-20T06:15:00),
   'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a z'
   ) )
2. I am using other method toLocaleString and it displays , 06/20/2023, 05:00:00 AM UTC

   public converDate(st:string) : string {
   const date = new Date(st);
   return date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
   timeZone: 'GMT',
   year: 'numeric',
   month: '2-digit',
   day: '2-digit',
   hour: '2-digit',
   minute: '2-digit',
   second: '2-digit',
   timeZoneName: 'short',
   });
   }

In the first method I am getting extra text (Central Daylight Time) and also Day of the week and no comma between month,day,year
In the second method, I am almost there, but want to replace UTC with GMT-5.
I heard UTC and GMT-5 denotes same time. Also is there a possibility of adding 'at' before time.
Can this be done.